# magento not sending contact form

Tags: zend-framework, magento-1.9

Hello

I'm using magento with a compo theme,

the problem i'm having, the magento is not sending the contact form, the other sales emails it sends normal, already looked at the crons and everything is fine.

no log found in / var for this.

i'm using magento 1.9.4, and shared host.

Comment: have you used default contact forms or have you create custom contact form?

Comment: hello i'm using  default contact forms.

Comment: have you send default email setting for contact form